# Windows Wallpaper with information

Tags: windows

What tool can I use to generate a Windows wallpaper at logon that contains user info?
I've seen it in several places, like in the screenshot.

[image]

I found [whoami](http://www.kewlit.com/whoami/), but it looks different and with less information than the screenshot I uploaded. (maybe the screenshot is a heavily configured version of it)

I've seen the same information in several Windows installs, but couldn't find the tool to do it.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the office we use [BGInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) by Sysinternals.  Easy to configure and you can have it execute external scripts if you want it pull in some specific information.

Comment: It can also pull in arbitrary information from the registry, etc.

Comment: If you don't have other tools to do it I think you can get it to log machine info to a database as well.

Answer (score 3):

[BGinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) from sysinternals will do this for you.

Comment: Highly useful program. Worth putting on all servers and configuring to be useful so they show more than just sysinfo (which server folk should be able to figure out quick enough) but app info and specific instructions as well.